# speed performance exporting to excel file using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Tags: c#, .net, excel

I am using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel to export local database table to excel file. There are five columns.

If rows are 400 it takes about 20 seconds,

If rows are 1200 it takes about 45 seconds,

If rows are 5000 it takes 250-300 seconds.

Is there a way to minimize the time to export? Or this is the maximum performance? If you can suggest to improve my code with respect to speed or suggest some alternative, I will appreciate. As it is working in background worker therefore invoking was necessary. My code is

```
       int rowCount = oLXTableDataGridView.RowCount;

        if (rowCount == 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No data to export.");

            return;

        }

        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                {
                     this.ExportFilepictureBox.Image = Properties.Resources.Animation;
                     labelexpoertolx.Text = "Preparing to export...";
                });


                object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;


                conn = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\dontdelete.sdf");
                String selectgroup = "SELECT * FROM OLXTable";
                int namecol = 1;
                int cellcol = 2;
                int emailcol = 3;
                int citycol = 4;
                int categorycol = 5;


                    try
                    {

                        Excel.Application xlApp1;
                        Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
                        Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;


                        xlApp1 = new Excel.Application();
                        xlWorkBook = xlApp1.Workbooks.Add(misValue);


                        xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
                        // MessageBox.Show("this is file");


                        xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, namecol].Value2 = "Name";
                        xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, cellcol].Value2 = "Cell No";
                        xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, emailcol].Value2 = "Email";
                        xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, citycol].Value2 = "City";
                        xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, categorycol].Value2 = "Category";

                        SqlCeDataReader reader = null;


                        //conn = new SqlCeConnection(selectnumbers);
                        conn.Open(); //open the connection
                        SqlCeCommand selecectnumberscmd = new SqlCeCommand(selectgroup, conn);
                        reader = selecectnumberscmd.ExecuteReader();
                        int i =  1;

                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, namecol].Value2 = reader.GetString(1);
                            xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, cellcol].Value2 = reader.GetInt64(2);
                            xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, emailcol].Value2 = reader.GetString(3); ;
                            xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, citycol].Value2 = reader.GetString(4);
                            xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, categorycol].Value2 = reader.GetString(5);
                            i++;

                        }
                        conn.Close();
                        xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
                        xlApp1.Quit();
                        releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
                        releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
                        releaseObject(xlApp1);



                        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                        {
                            this.ExportFilepictureBox.Image = null;
                            labelexpoertolx.Text = "";
                        });


                    }
                    catch (Exception e13)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Error Exporting data" + e13.Message);
                        conn.Close();


                    }
                    Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
```

and

```
private void releaseObject(object obj)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
            obj = null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            obj = null;
            MessageBox.Show("Exception Occured while releasing object " + ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            GC.Collect();
        }
    }
```

Comment: may be better for code review

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are dead set on using interop then it is best to first create an array of values then write it out in one foul swoop rather than cycling through rows - interop is notoriously slow at this

Personally, I'd recommend ditching interop and using an open xml library such as [EPPlus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/) for this type of task. I find it easier to use and generally much more performant. As a bonus it gets rid of all that irksome messy releasing com object marshal stuff ;-)

This would replace everything inside your `try` block with something like this:

```
using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage())
{
    ExcelWorksheet ws = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Data");
    ws.Cells[1, namecol].Value = "Name";
    ws.Cells[1, cellcol].Value = "Cell No";
    ws.Cells[1, emailcol].Value = "Email";
    ws.Cells[1, citycol].Value = "City";
    ws.Cells[1, categorycol].Value = "Category";

    SqlCeDataReader reader = null;

    conn.Open(); //open the connection
    SqlCeCommand selecectnumberscmd = new SqlCeCommand(selectgroup, conn);
    reader = selecectnumberscmd.ExecuteReader();
    int i = 1;

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        ws.Cells[i, namecol].Value = reader.GetString(1);
        ws.Cells[i, cellcol].Value = reader.GetInt64(2);
        ws.Cells[i, emailcol].Value = reader.GetString(3); ;
        ws.Cells[i, citycol].Value = reader.GetString(4);
        ws.Cells[i, categorycol].Value = reader.GetString(5);
        i++;

    }

    conn.Close();

    //Now you have options to export the file - just save someplace, get a byte array or get a reference to the output stream etc with some of the following:

    package.SaveAs(someFilePathString);
    someByteArrayVariable =  package.GetAsByteArray();
    package.Stream;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As an alternative you can use [SwiftExcel](https://github.com/RomanPavelko/SwiftExcel) library (disclaimer: I wrote the library), like EPPlus it does not use interop, but has better performance as streams data directly to the file, which faster and does not have any memory impact on huge batches.

Here is Nuget command to add it to your project:

```
PM> Install-Package SwiftExcel
```

And here is how you can use it:

```
using (var ew = new ExcelWriter("C:\\temp\\test.xlsx"))
{
    for (var row = 1; row <= 100; row++)
    {
        for (var col = 1; col <= 10; col++)
        {
            ew.Write($"row:{row}-col:{col}", col, row);
        }
    }
}
```